# Continuity and partial differentiability for $f(x, y) := e^x - 1$

Tags: continuity, partial-derivative

> Given
>
> $$M =\left\lbrace(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus 0 \ \mid\ x = y\right\rbrace$$
>
> and
>
> $$f(x, y) := e^x - 1$$
>
> when $(x, y) \in M$,
>
> otherwise
>
> $$f(x, y) := 0,$$
>
> I have to examine whether the function is continious and partial differentiable at $(x, y) = 0$ or not.

This exercise looks a little bit weird to me since it was part of an exam and since it looks a little bit too easy to me. I might've done something wrong.

**Approach**

First, we note that

$$(x, y) = 0\quad \implies \quad(x, y) = (0, 0) \quad\implies\quad (x, y) \in M.$$

**Continuity**

We can simply plug the values into the function:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} e^x - 1 = \lim_{x\to 0} e^x - 1 = e^0 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0.$$

Therefore, the function is continious at $(0, 0).$

**Partial differentiability**

$$\lim_{{(0,y)}\to (0,0)}  e^x - 1 = e^0 - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0,$$

and similar

$$\lim_{(x, 0)\to 0} e^x - 1 = 0.$$

Since the critical values do exist in both cases, the function is partial differentiable at $(x, y) = (0, 0).$

Comment: I see a couple of issues here. First in the approach, $(x,y)=0$ is not in $M$, by definition. Second, for the differentiability, when you approach along the $x$ and $y$ axis, the function is simply $0$, because you are not in $M$ so your difference quotients should look like $\frac{0-0}{x}$ and $\frac{0-0}{y}$; the value of $e^x-1$ is irrelevant along these paths.

Comment: Also for continuity, you should discuss two cases, the first being an approach along $M$, which you did, but also what happens when you approach along a path not in $M$ (this case is of course trivial so maybe you knew this and left it out because it is simple enough).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 0 is indeed not in M. I will have a look on it tomorrow (its midnight here) and share my thoughts with you then. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of nonsense going on here.

In the first place, the function $f$ is defined on all of ${\mathbb R}^2$. It is $=0$ everywhere, except on the set $M:=\{(x,y)\>|\>x=y\ne0\}$. For $(x,y)\in M$ it is stipulated that $f(x,y):=e^x-1$.

The function $f$ is continuous at all points $(x,y)\notin M\cup\{{\bf 0}\}$, because it is $\equiv0$ in a full neighborhood of such points. If $(x_0,y_0)\in M$ then $f(x_0,y_0)\ne0$, but $f(x,y)=0$ at points $(x,y)$ arbitrarily close to $(x_0,y_0)$. It follows that $f$ is discontinuous at all points of $M$.

Remains the point ${\bf 0}$. I claim that $f$ is continuous there. *Proof:* The exponential function is continuous. Hence, given an $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|e^x-1|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|\leq\delta$. Assume now that $(x,y)\in B_\delta({\bf 0})$. If $(x,y)\notin M$ then $f(x,y)=0$. If $(x,y)\in M$ then from $|x|\leq\delta$ it follows that $|f(x,y)|=|e^x-1|<\epsilon$.

Since $f$ is $\equiv0$ on both the $x$- and the $y$-axis it is obvious that
$${\partial f\over\partial x}(0,0)={\partial f\over\partial y}(0,0)=0\ .$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What do you mean by $\equiv$ in this specific context?

Comment: "$\,\equiv0\,$" just means "identically zero".